# Language question in Mark 15:34

Tags: mark, translation-philosophy

In Mark 15:34, why was part of the verse left in the Aramaic language instead of being translated into English? Why, if the rest was translated, does that line remain the same?

> 15:34 Around three o’clock Jesus cried out with a loud voice, “*Eloi, Eloi, lema sabachthani?*” which means, “My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?”

Answer (score 7):

Because at that point, for that clause, the Greek switches to Aramaic (they are Aramaic words written in Greek letters, a practice known as [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration)) with the interpretation following.

> Mark 15:34 καὶ τῇ ἐνάτῃ ὥρᾳ ἐβόησεν ὁ Ἰησοῦς φωνῇ μεγάλῃ· **ἐλωι ἐλωι λεμα σαβαχθανι;** ὅ ἐστιν μεθερμηνευόμενον· ὁ θεός μου ὁ θεός μου, εἰς τί ἐγκατέλιπες με;

To translate the Aramaic would make the verse odd. It would read like this:

> Around three o’clock Jesus cried out with a loud voice, “My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?” which means, “My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?”

Comment: But, why didn't the author simply translate the first statement in the first place and simply omit the rest (from "which" onwards). Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe he was trying to make it clear why the bystanders thought he was calling Elijah?

Comment: Ah, yes, I recall that now. That's obviously it. :)